# "Connection to/with the server was/has been lost"

Tags: participles, present-tense

Which one is correct?

> Connection to the server **was** lost.
>
> Connection to the server **has been** lost.

Also, should *to* or *with* be used with *server*?

Comment: Nearly everyone of them is a plausible alternative, depending on the context, depending on what exactly you want to convey. You may paste the entire paragraph to show the context. Or voluntarily withdraw your question as frivolous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are grammatical. The first uses the past tense (‘was lost’), which indicates that the connection was lost at a specific time in the past. The second uses the present perfect construction (‘has been lost’), which indicates that the loss of the connection has present relevance. So, if the loss of connection occurred, let us say, last week, but it’s now restored, you’d say ‘Connection to the server was lost’. If, however, the loss of connection is recent, and you’re still suffering from it, then you’d say ‘Connection to the server has been lost’.

‘Connection **to**’ is fine, although the verb ‘connect’ can be followed by ‘to’ or ‘with’ depending on the context.

Comment: +1 However, as you conclude, "depending on the context." How would we know what was intended?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Barrie and will probably use that explanation of the difference between the two tenses at least twice today, because the subtleties of present perfect tense are extremely difficult for a lot of non-native English speakers.

"To" implies a one-way relationship. The important thing is there is a connection. "With" implies reciprocity, and is preferred when talking about people, but doesn't make any difference with inanimate objects.

Compare "I connected with Mary the moment we met" (We had an instant rapport) with/to "I connected to Mary the moment we met" (I attached myself to her in some way) and the difference becomes clearer.